# Проблема с обработчиком функции "Поделиться статьей" в Django

Tags: python, django

Python 3. Проект блога на Django.

Для расширения функций блога в хранилище обработчиков views.py добавлена функция def post_share (request, post_id) со следующим кодом:

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
# Получение статьи по идентификатору
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id, status = 'published')
sent = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    # Форма была отправлена на сохранение.
    form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        # Все поля формы прошли валидацию 
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        # Отправка электронной почты
        post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
        subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
        message - 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
        send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
        sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
        return render (request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post':post, 'form':form}, {'sent':sent},)
```

Форма заполнения данных forms.py выглядит следующим образом:

```
from django import forms
class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required = False, widget = forms.Textarea)
```

Отправка электронной почты - в settings.py добавлены настройки:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'здесь моя Google-почта'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'соответственно пароль от неё'
EAMIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIl_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Для обработчика добавлен URL - шаблон в urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 


app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    # path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/',
         views.post_detail,
         name='post_detail'),
    path( '<int:post_id>/share/', views.post_share, name = 'post_share'),
]
```

Далее, оформлен HTML - шаблон для отображения формы share.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Share a post{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {% if sent %}
    <h1> Email successfully sent </h1>
    <p> "{{ post.title }}" was successfully sent to {{ form.cleaned_data.to }}.</p>
  {% else %}
    <h1> Share "{{ post.title }}" by e-mail </h1>
    <form action="." method="post">
      {{ form.as_p }}
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" value="Send e-mail">
    </form>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

И, конечно, прикручена кнопка для этого в detail.html:

```
<a href="{% url "blog:post_share" post.id %}"> Share this post </a>
```

После запуска сервера и попытки поделиться статьей сервер ругается и выдает следующее:
[image: Сообщение об ошибке]

Насколько верно я понял, текст ошибки сообщает, что в приложении blog в обработчике views функция post_share не возвращает ответ(response) на запрос (request), находящийся в обработчике.

Учусь по книге Django в примерах. А.Меле.
Свой код неоднократно проверил с учебником, а затем с официальным в репозитории на GitHub`e.

Судя по картинке сервер ругается не на код, а настройки предлагаемые самим Django.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Также существует проблема с подключением почты google. 
Настройки less secure apps - разрешил.

Спасибо)

Comment: Могу предположить, что при валидации формы нужно всё-таки вернуть HttpResponse, а у вас ничего не возвращает. Но это не точно

Comment: Верните пустой HttpResponse(""), например

Comment: return render () как раз и должен возвращать HTTPResponse, судя по описанию этой функции.
Она импортируется отдельно

Comment: ну так при валидации формы вы ее не вернули

Comment: @Александр
Т.е в блоке if функции-обработчика post_share надо прописать последней строкой return render () ?

Comment: Да, но не факт, что это поможет. У вас серьезные расхождения с оригиналом https://github.com/lancelote/django_by_example/blob/master/mysite/blog/views.py. Вы либо неверно оформили код либо напутали с отступами. Иначе смысл совсем другой

Comment: @ Я могу пояснить расхождения. Я делаю главу за главой последовательно, а на этом же гитхабе уже законченный код. Я по мне и сверяю периодически свой код. 
Здесь я ошибся только с отступом в блоке if в обработчике post_share.
Но на ноуте у меня все правильно, иначе VS Code ругался бы на синтаксис. 
А здесь выдает ошибки даже не связанные с написанным кодом (

Comment: здесь нет синтаксической ошибки - она логическая. Приведите код с теми отступами, который вы запускаете. Отступы в пайтоне влияют на порядок выполнения строк кода, их нельзя менять

Comment: @Stanlyzoolo так при клике по ссылке обрабатывается гет запрос, а в функции Вы обрабатываете `POST`. Поэтому и возвращается `None`.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук
Т.е. попробовать заменить if request.method == "POST" на if request.method == "GET"?

Comment: вообще убрать `if request.method == "POST"`. Функция по дефолту обрабатывает гет запрос.

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук
Сделал как Вы подсказали и форма отобразилась!
Все как и должно быть. 
Но теперь ругается на метод "POST" потому, что форма была заполнена, но не может быть отправлена обработчиком. 
Если я все правильно понимаю, GET нужен для получения формы, POST для отправки формы после ее валидирования. 

POST нужен, но теперь не могу понять где

Comment: @Александр, спасибо за помощь, нашел ошибку немного в другом месте!

Comment: @ДмитрийДмитрук,спасибо за помощь, нашел ошибку немного в другом месте!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел важную ошибку в русскоязычной версии книги А.Меле "Django на примерах":

В коде обработчика post_share (Поделиться статьей) допущена ошибка - строка return render () должно закрывать блок if request.method == 'POST', а не блок с проверкой валидности if form.is_valid.

Правильная редакция кода:

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Получение статьи по идентификатору
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id, status = 'published')
    sent = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Все поля формы прошли валидацию 
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            # Отправка электронной почты
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title,)
            message = 'Read "%s" at %s\n\n%s\'s comments: %s' % (
                post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render (request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post':post, 'form':form, 'sent':sent})
```

Запрос GET и отправка путем POST будут работать корректно.

Comment: Так я выше ж на нее ссылку и кидал

Answer (score 1):

У тебя почему-то blog/4/share вызывается с методом GET, а во вьюхе post_share определено поведение только для POST запросов. Естественно функция просто возвращает None.

Возможно, ты вызываешь blog/4/share просто вбивая url, а не через форму?

Так же советую добавить в form action="share"

Comment: Цифра 4 - это значение поста в списке постов. Список постов открываю запуском сервера и приставки в url /blog. 
Ну и, соответственно, какой пост не выбери у него будет порядковый номер. 
Почему ошибка Request Method: GET я не понимаю пока.
Но нашел вот такое
Результат request.method == "POST" является логическим значением - True, если текущий запрос пользователя был выполнен с использованием метода HTTP POST, в False в противном случае (обычно это означает, что HTTP "GET", но там также являются другими методами).

Comment: Емли ты открываешб через строку в браузере любой url, он запросится по методу GET. Как ты попадаешь на страницу blog/id/share?

Comment: Добрался до ноута...))

Запускаю сервер путем python3 manage.py runserver, далее добавляю blog к http://127.0.0.1:8000 и попадаю на страницу со списком статей. Я набросал пять полупустых статей. Выбираю любую статью и нажимаю под ней "Поделиться" и попадаю на страницу, которая приложена скрином выше.

Когда прыгаю по статьям терминал отображает: [04/Nov/2019 19:42:47] "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1275

При попытке поделиться Traceback и следующее:
[04/Nov/2019 19:51:01] "GET /blog/4/share/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59889

Comment: А, ты видимо переходишь по ссылке в detail.html естественно страница запрашивается с GET. Поменяй тег a на примерно такую кнопку: <button type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="{% url "blog:post_share" post.id %}">Submit</button>

Comment: Спешу Вам ответить!
Нашел две важные ошибки, которые порождали друг друга: 
Во первых, я сам неправильно располагал строку с переменной form неправильно над инструкцией if request.method == 'POST'.
Во вторых, в русскоязычной версии книги в коде самого обработчика допущена ошибка:    строка return render () должно закрывать вышеуказанный блок, а не блок с проверкой валидности.
Вот! Спасибо Вам за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

Встретился с подобной проблемой. Решил только когда в views.py добавил строку:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

Иначе строка:

```
send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
```

выбрасывала ошибку.